# Cast Chrome desktop browser tab to Android device

Tags: screen-mirroring

I want to mirror the content from a Chrome desktop tab on my Android device.

Is it possible to cast a Chrome browser tab *from desktop* to an Android (OS 8.1) device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [WebRTC Desktop Sharing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-desktop-sharing/nkemblooioekjnpfekmjhpgkackcajhg?hl=en) extension on your Chrome browser for Desktop. Click on its icon → Chrome tab + Speakers → choose your tab to share → wait for the extension to give you a URL.

Use that URL into your Android device's browser. It will take few seconds to initialize everything and then you can have a real-time Chrome tab sharing from Desktop to anywhere.

Alternatively, if you are using Windows, enable Remote Desktop Sharing in it, setup a Remote Desktop connection and use [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.chromeremotedesktop) app to share the whole screen with Android. I haven't tested this one though.

Comment: Two years and two days later and found this answer via Google. Option two works a treat for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as "Cast" goes, you can only cast to Chromecast devices or Android TV devices from cast-enabled devices. Not from other devices to your phone.

What you can do is use apps like Splashtop or TeamViewer, to "handle" or use your computer from the mobile device.